# C++, undefined reference to a function that despite including it's header

Tags: c++, header-files, undefined-reference, default-arguments

I'm pretty new to C++, and working through a book called "Accelerated C++." In one of the chapters you are suppose to make a program that, given a string of text, tells you what line(s) each word appears on. To break up all of the words in the string, i used a function called 'split' from a different source file, but included its header file so I could use it. It didn't work though. For the life of me I can't figure out why the linker tells me "undefined reference to 'split(std::string const&)'

split.cpp:

```
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <vector>
#include "split.h"

using namespace std;

bool space(char c) {
    return isspace(c);
}

bool not_space(char c) {
    return !isspace(c);
}

vector<string> split(const string& s) {
    vector<string> ret;
    string::const_iterator i = s.begin();

    while (i != s.end()) {

        i = find_if(it, s.end(), not_space);

        string::const_iterator j = i;
        j = find_if(j, s.end(), space);
        if (i != s.end())
            ret.push_back(string(i, j));

        i = j;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

split.h:

```
#ifndef GUARD_split_h
#define GUARD_split_h

#include <string>
#include <vector>

bool space(char);
bool not_space(char);
std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string&);

#endif
```

Word_Counter.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include "split.h"

using namespace std;

map<string, vector<int> > xref(istream& in, vector<string>
        find_words(const string&) = split) {

    string line;
    int line_number = 0;
    map<string, vector<int> > ret;

    while (getline(in, line)) {
        ++line_number;

        vector<string> words = find_words(line);

        for (vector<string>::const_iterator it = words.begin();
                it != words.end(); it++)
            ret[*it].push_back(line_number);
    }
    return ret;
}

int main() {

map<string, vector<int> > ret = xref(cin);

for(map<string, vector<int> >::const_iterator it = ret.begin();
    it != ret.end(); it++) {

    cout << it->first << "occurs on line(s): ";

    vector<int>::const_iterator line_it = it->second.begin();
    cout << *line_it;

    line_it++;

    while(line_it != it->second.end()) {
        cout << ", " << *line_it;
        line_it++;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
return 0;
```

}

I've been having a tough time with headers in general lately. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How do you build your program? Can you edit to the question the exact build line? Do you include _both_ `.o` (or, well, `.cpp`) files?

Comment: All I type is: "g++ Word_Counter.cpp -o Word_Counter." All three files are in the same directory.

Comment: Oh what the heck. I just typed "g++ Word_Counter.cpp split.cpp" and (after i fixed one typo) it worked. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have sources split in several files, you need to make the compiler aware of all them. The simplest way is to list *all* `.cpp` files (not `.h` files!) on the command line:

```
g++ Word_Counter.cpp split.cpp -o Word_Counter
```

Comment: So even though Word_Counter.cpp includes split.h, the compiler won't grab split.cpp automatically? Was there actually anything wrong with my header file?

Comment: @LiamTyler, I see no problems with your header. However, just `#include`'ing a header does not make the compiler aware of the corresponding source. It works on a simpler level: `#include`ing a file simply inserts its text in the position of `#include`, and nothing more.

Comment: Oh, i never knew it literally just inserted the text where the #include is. Thank you so much

Comment: And if you have to deal with a large project that deals with CMakeLists.txt, those files are listed in `add_library`.